# Is it possible to add comments on each line of a split up parallel assignment in Python?

Tags: python

I have the following scenario: I have a function which returns multiple values:

```
def func(x):
     return x+1, x+2, x+3, x+4
```

I'd like to do the following:

```
a, # this is the x+1 value
b, # this is the x+2 value
c, # this is the x+3 value
d = func(7) # and this is the x+4 one!
```

i.e. I want the simple assignment

```
a, b, c, d = func(7)
```

but with comments in between describing each variable.

The function I have is obviously more complex than this, and so I'd like to include many details about each variable (1-2 sentences) that is output. Is there a way to do this? I tried adding a \ character before the # on each line as well as after the comment on each line, but neither work

In my experience, one can call a function with multiple parameters, and do this sort of multi line commenting (without any need for \ characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parentheses:

```
(
    a,  # some facts
        # some more
    b,  # look at me!
    c,
    d,  # I like to say stuff
        # I should just write doctrings
) = func(42)
```

But really, you should just be documenting this in a docstring for your function. Any text-editor/IDE will surface that information at your fingertips.

Note, according to [PEP 8, the official style-guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length):

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python’s implied
> line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines
> can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in
> parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash
> for line continuation.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use parenthesis

```
>>> (
...     a, # One
...     b, # Two
...     c, # Three
...     d  # Four
... ) = func(7)
```